# Developer Removed from Sale to Prepare for submission

Tags: app-store-connect

How to remove the current build from iTunes Connect where the app is in "Developer Removed from Sale" status? Also, the older version should be made "Ready for Sale". Please help me. I have unknowingly Released the version of that app.

I cannot remove the current build from iTunes Connect now. The build doesn't show up any delete button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to submit a new version with a new build. It's both not possible to a) either update the build of a live version (which was on the store) nor b) to switch to an older version.

Your flow will look like this:
1) Create new version in iTunes Connect
2) Create & upload new build with fixes for this version
3) Submit to the store. If it's a critical bug fix, you might want to request an expedited app review. https://developer.apple.com/support/app-review/

> **Expedited App Review:**
>   If you face extenuating circumstances, you can request the review of your app to be expedited. These circumstances include fixing a critical bug in your app on the App Store or releasing your app to coincide with an event you are directly associated with.
>
> **Urgent Bug Fix:**
>   If you've submitted an update to fix a critical bug in your app on the App Store and you are requesting an expedited review, be sure to include the steps to reproduce the bug on the current version of your app.